# Will any IE security setting prevent access to WebBrowser's ObjectForScripting?

Tags: internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

I have an application that sets a `WebBrowser`'s `ObjectForScripting` property to a custom object so that the user can access it from javascript code using `window.external`. It have always worked fine but now one of my customers seems unable to access it.

I cannot be 100% sure what the problem is because I'd have to access his computer and I don't want to bug him that much since he's a customer and seems like he found a workaround to what he was trying to do. But it seems to me like he cannot access the object at `window.external`.

Other than unchecking `Active Scripting` (which doesn't actually prevents access to `window.external`), do you know any security setting that will prevent access to the object at `window.external`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure the external object is [safe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [allowed for scripting.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0908yt1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)